# How many elts from a list are less distant than a value from N others lists

Tags: python, list, comparison

So I'll try to explain my problem with an example.

```
L1 = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
L2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
L3 = [1.1, 9.5, 12, 14, 80, 90, 100]
L4 = [16, 25, 30, 40, 50, 150, 200, 250]
L5 = [15, 16, 18, 19, 29, 300, 350, 500, 600]
```

If I take one element from L1, I want to know if there are less than 2 other elements from `L2+L3+L4+L5` that are at a distance < value (let's say 1.5).

So for L1[0] = 0 : L2[0] and L3[0] are at a distance < 1.5. So it's OK.
For L1[3] = 15: L3[3], L4[0], L5[0] and L5[1] are at a distance < 1.5 => Not Ok

Same for L2 with `L1+L3+L4+L5`, etc... I need to check that there isn't any element close to more than 2 others.

I'm looking for a fast way of checking this condition. My current approach uses list comprehension, i quite long, and needs one function for comparing 2 lists, one for comparing 3, ...

```
def duo_overlap(t1, t2):

    id_t1 = [x for x in range(len(t1)) for y in range(len(t2)) if abs(t1[x] - t2[y]) < 0.3]
    id_t2 = [y for y in range(len(t2)) for x in range(len(t1)) if abs(t2[y] - t1[x]) < 0.3]

    return id_t1, id_t2
```

Thanks for the suggestion :)

**EDIT: Timeline list as I use them:**

- `F20 = [0.0, 50.0, 100.0]`
- `F40 = [0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0, 125.0]`
- `F50 = [0.0, 20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0, 120.0, 140.0]`
- `F100 = [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0, 110.0, 120.0, 130.0, 140.0]`
- `F125 = [0.0, 8.0, 16.0, 24.0, 32.0, 40.0, 48.0, 56.0, 64.0, 72.0, 80.0, 88.0, 96.0, 104.0, 112.0, 120.0, 128.0, 136.0, 144.0]`

Function to design one:

```
def time_builder(f, t0=0, tf=150):
    return list(np.round(np.arange(t0, tf, 1/f*1000),3))
```

Comment: Are the input list always ordered?

Comment: Yes, I used a random example here, but in reality, each list is a timeline of a square waveform at a given frequency. Thus they are ordered and `len(L1) <= len(L2) <= ... <= len(L5)` because of the frequencies being ordered as well.

Comment: But `len(L1) > len(L2)` !

Comment: Yeah that's just in the example above... I can change that by adding a few values. Thou it should not really matter what are the sizes of the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Since each list is ordered, you can solve it with a heap in O(nlog(n)).

The basic idea is first to merge sort the lists, then append them into a queue one by one, and keep only the elements you want in the queue.

```
def duo_overlap(*t, value): # Notice that 'keyword-only' arguments are only allowed in Python 3
    num_in_queue = [0 for i in t] # the num of elements in heap of each list
    iters = [0 for i in t] # what's the next element to enter the heap
    min_heap = [] # a heap to get the minimum of the rest elements
    queue = deque() # a queue to hold all elements (from which we can get the number of the elements) that's at a distance < value from the current element.
    result = [[] for i in t]
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if iters[i] != len(t[i]):
            heapq.heappush(min_heap, (t[i][iters[i]], i))
            iters[i] += 1
    while min_heap:
        next_element, i = heapq.heappop(min_heap)
        if iters[i] != len(t[i]): # get the next minimun element, and push the next element of the list from which the next minimun element is.
            heapq.heappush(min_heap, (t[i][iters[i]], i))
            iters[i] += 1
        while queue and abs(queue[0][0] - next_element) >= value: # pop all elements that's at a distance >= value from the next element.
            num_in_queue[queue.popleft()[1]] -= 1
        result[i].append(len(queue) - num_in_queue[i]) # so you now get the number of elements that's less than and at a distance < value from the next element.
        queue.append((next_element, i))
        num_in_queue[i] += 1
    return result




duo_overlap(time_builder(20), time_builder(40), time_builder(50), time_builder(100), time_builder(125), value=0.3)
```

The result is

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
 [3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

which is the num of elements which is LESS THAN and at a distance < value.

Notice here that if two elements from different lists are equal, than the one from the previous list is less than the other. It's just a trick and will not influence the result.

You can get a similar function to get the GREAT THAN one, or you can reverse the list like

```
list(reversed(
    list(map(
        lambda t: list(reversed(t)),
        duo_overlap(*list(reversed(
            list(map(
                lambda t: [-t[-1-i] for i in range(len(t))],
                (time_builder(20), time_builder(40), time_builder(50), time_builder(100), time_builder(125))
            ))
        )), value=0.3)
    ))
))
```

The result:

```
[[4, 2, 3],
 [3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
 [2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I know that's not very elegant, but `heapq` can only build a heap with `<`. Maybe it's a good idea to find a better module.

And add the two list together, you will get the answer.

Comment: A lot of new stuff in that answer for me. I'm gonna look into it tomorrow. Thanks a lot for the reply !

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a particularly smart or elegant algorithm, but you can just loop over the lists. If you do it intelligently, you can minimize the number of comparisons (although the overall complexity will still be O(n<sup>2</sup>)).

```
def check_lists_elements(lists, margin, max_close):
    # Lists with counts of close elements
    counts = [[0] * len(lst) for lst in lists]
    for i_lst, lst in enumerate(lists):
        for i_elem, elem in enumerate(lst):
            # Only check the lists after the current one to avoid repeating comparisons
            for i_other_lst, other_lst in enumerate(lists[i_lst + 1:], i_lst + 1):
                for i_other_elem, other_elem in enumerate(other_lst):
                    if abs(elem - other_elem) < margin:
                        # When a close pair is found increase the count for both elements
                        counts[i_lst][i_elem] += 1
                        counts[i_other_lst][i_other_elem] += 1
                        # Check if there are too many repetitions
                        if counts[i_lst][i_elem] > max_close or counts[i_other_lst][i_other_elem] > max_close:
                            return False
                    elif other_elem - elem >= margin:
                        # We can stop iterating after the difference is too big
                        break
    return True

L1 = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
L2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
L3 = [1.1, 9.5, 12, 14, 80, 90, 100]
L4 = [16, 25, 30, 40, 50, 150, 200, 250]
L5 = [15, 16, 18, 19, 29, 300, 350, 500, 600]

lists = [L1, L2, L3, L4, L5]
print(check_lists_elements(lists, margin=1.5, max_close=2))

>>> False
```